# How would school uniforms be designed?

Tags: magic, history, clothing, gender, education

In my fantasy world, there are academies where young people are taught the ways of magic, the first one during the early-late medieval period. Due to some of its origin, this one is also the first to normalize both genders studying as equals.

Since this is a private school, the students wear school uniforms. I was wondering, how are school uniforms exactly designed? At first in the medieval era, the students mainly wore robes and lengthy clothing. However, the uniform fashion changes throughout history. What would make the uniforms more gender specific, and in how fashion trends change in a history, as well as in how a culture's fashion forms, what would cause the idea of the girl's uniform having a short skirt and long stockings, rather than a long dress or pants like the boys?

Comment: ??? Uniforms most usually reflect that typical clothing style of the time they were adopted, which is usually decades out of date. *Nobody* wore a uniform in the Middle Ages. Not soldiers, not servants, and definitely not school pupils or university students. And *everybody* in the Middle Ages wore gender-specific clothes; in many places and in many times it was illegal for women to wear men's clothes. Girls' uniforms having short skirts simply does not happen in Europe, and, as far as I know, it also does not happen in the USA. (Unless your religion says that a knee-length skirt is "short".)

Comment: @AlexP I believe Monks and Priests had uniforms. And some of the time [young boys did not wear gender specific clothes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breeching_(boys)).

Comment: Instead of coming to us with a specific problem you're having with building your world, you're asking us to build part of your world for you. Questions asking for help brainstorming or generating ideas are off topic for this site.

Answer (score 2):

**Gendered Uniforms appear as Schools Become Commonplace**

The standard school uniform is *smart-casual* from the time-period that education became mandatory. This should be used to say something about your world. If education became mandatory a long long time ago the uniform will not reflect the clothes of the time.

When there is only one Academy in the country, being a student there is much more important than whether you are a boy or girl. So the uniform might be unisex. It will be more complicated and expensive because the Academy is exclusive in its membership.

When schools become common this goes away. The uniform moves towards casual wear.  Here are some Irish schoolchildren.

[image]

Standard public school uniforms.

[image]

Secondary school uniforms.

[image]

The trousers are a newish invention.

[image]

Different private school uniforms.

[image]

Boys uniforms.

**Note:** The open blazer and or necktie is more of a Northern Ireland or British thing.

But -- wait a minute -- these look nothing like casual wear. There are no bluejeans. Casual wear does not include labelled collars.  And the skirt is quickly becoming extinct.

It is because the uniform was created in the 1920s when the above was closer to casual wear at the time.

Once everyone was wearing the same thing it got stuck that way because (a) no one wants to be the first one to change and (b) being unusual and/or uncomfortable is good for discipline in schools.

If the uniform is old enough there is also (c) this style of dress now only carries the meaning of "school uniform". It no longer carries the old-fashioned or sexist overtones.

One possibility for changes is (d) all school uniforms in the country are made at the same factory. In that case the factory can make changes to simplify all uniforms in the country. For example change the material to something lighter or easier to clean; replace buttons with zips; change shirt length; create a different range of sizes; or modify the collar. That way you might get an old fashioned uniform made from modern materials.

Answer (score 1):

School uniforms, like all uniforms, are designed by a mix of practical reasons and ideological reasons. For example I read somewhere that that the 3 buttons at the wrist of military uniforms were introduced to avoid soldiers cleaning their snot dripping nose on the sleeves, which was seen as degrading for the decorum of the army.

As for schools, short skirts for girls are not always a norm: maybe in Japan, but in other countries, while girls are mandated to wear a skirt to enforce gender roles (skirt = girl, pants = boys), the length is much more modesty oriented and showing legs is frowned upon. I have honestly no idea what is the rationale behind the short in short skirts for girls in Japan, and having read that some schools have recently banned showing napes for girls (allegedly because it might arouse boys) just increased my confusion.

Coming back to your question, basically you need to decide which code is being enforced on the wearers, and how that will be translated in the uniforms. You might add a differentiation based on the year of attendance, so that at a glance it is possible to tell a novice from a more advanced student and so on.

Comment: What is the story with this ponytail ban? Ponytails, necks, and boys have been around since time began. Is this "ban" in response to some recent event?

Comment: @Daron it's happened around the end of March this year https://www.outkick.com/japanese-schools-ban-ponytails-because-they-may-sexually-excite-the-boys/

Comment: Are they still allowed play the game where you shove both index fingers into your friends' bumhole?

Comment: A good response would be all the schoolgirls getting Liza Monelli cuts.

Answer (score 0):

Change the ideology of the people.  The middle ages Had a strict gender divide with an religious infoces on modesty and sexual purity before marriage.

Your setting still needs a strong gender divide,(or else there would be no need for two uniforms) but with a less concern for modesty.

Either 1. Pre marriage sex for young people isn't considered a big deal. Perhaps this can be explained by birth control spell combined with slight religous reforms so that pre marriage sex isn't always considered fornication. Perhaps young ladies that go to school actually do so with the hope of find a wealth wizard husband?

2. Sexual  purity is still important but nudity is less connect to temptation. It is not uncommon for members of the opposite sex to see each other in little or no clothing in a non sexual context so a short skirt isn't considered a big deal.